# Dart final keyword performance impact

Tags: dart

I am aware that once assigned a value, a `final` variable's value cannot be changed. Does the keyword `final` have a positive **performance** impact compared to a not-final variable?

Comment: No nothing significant that I know of. Especially with AOT compilation. In the VM, it might be able to do some optimization, but it's not something you should be worrying about unless you have performance issues. It's there primarily for clarity in programs and to prevent unintentional reassignments.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore I was assuming the compiler can make optimizations based on the fact the variable is never going to change. Is that not the case?

Comment: Not necessarily. Especially with AOT compilation.

Comment: For local variables, the compiler can easily determine whether a variable is reassigned or not, so if there is an optimization opportunity, the compiler should be able to do it for you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For local variables, there is no advantage. Any competent compiler can detect whether a local variable is assigned to, whether it's declared `final` or not.

For instance variables, it's harder to detect whether there is a subclass overriding the variable, or some other implementation of the interface. That means that even if the variable is final, the compiler can rarely trust that for anything. A compiler with access to the whole program might detect that there is no assignment anywhere.
It makes a difference for your API though.

For static and top-level variables there might be a slight advantage in making the variable final. It means that local analysis can know that the value won't change, even without seeing the entire program.

All in all, anything but local variables, you should make unchanging variables final because it's good modelling, not because you worry about performance. For local variables, it doesn't matter.