# What keyword should variables in functions have in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I know how to name variables in classes but how does it relate to functions? I've noticed that some devs use final keywords for variables that never change in functions, but the others use var even in functions.

Which of the following examples is recommended in terms of clean code and performance?

```dart
doSomething() {
  final int i = 1;
  print(i.toString());
}

 doSomething() {
  final i = 1;
  print(i.toString());
}

doSomething() {
  int i = 1;
  print(i.toString());
}

doSomething() {
  var i = 1;
  print(i.toString());
}
```

Comment: Note to anyone who might consider this opinion-based: it's possible to answer this question objectively from the documentation because Dart provides a style guide that is further enforced by the linter.

Comment: The style guide does not provide a definitive answer; as you noted, it ultimately leaves it up to the reader.  And while the linter can enforce a style, it's still up to the user to decide *which* style to enforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official Dart [documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#do-follow-a-consistent-rule-for-var-and-final-on-local-variables), using `final` vs `var` is a matter of taste; the important part is to be consistent. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64495620/15170120), most compilers will notice that a variable is never reassigned whether or not you make it final. The same documentation link says that most variables should not have a datatype explicitly assigned, just the keyword `final` or `var`. I personally disagree because of bad experiences with accidentally retyping variables, but that is the official recommendation.

If you make the variable final, then the compiler will enforce its status as read-only. The linter recommends that you always use `final` for variables that aren't reassigned.

Answer (score 1):

#### Should I use `var` or type annotation such as `int`?

Here's my approach:

In Dart, The `var` keyword is used to declare a variable. The Dart compiler automatically knows the type of data based on the assigned variable because Dart is an infer type language.

So, if you *know* the type before, you can use `var`, since Dart can infer the type for you automatically. For example:

```
var name = 'Andrew'
```

However, if you *don't know* the type before, you can use type annotation:

```
int age;
...
age = 5;
```

- For more explanation, you can take a look at [https://www.javatpoint.com/dart-variable](https://www.javatpoint.com/dart-variable#) at the "How to Declare Variable in Dart" section, they explain the answer to your question in greater detail, (I have used their example)

Answer (score 0):

It's preferable to use final for values that don't change.

And use linter if you are not sure.

- `dart pub add lints` - official lints

```yaml
#analysis_options.yaml
include: package:lints/recommended.yaml
```

- `dart pub add zekfad_lints` - lints I like to use

```yaml
#analysis_options.yaml
include: package:zekfad_lints/untyped/dart.yaml

# If you are using flutter
#include: package:zekfad_lints/untyped/flutter.yaml
```